# How to extend the Java API to be able to introduce new annotations

Tags: annotations, java

Can you explain me how I can extend or change the JAVA-API to using two new Annotations `@any` and `@option` to allow Multiplicies in Java?

The main idea for the Multiplicities is the follow:

> Multiplicities help to solve many maintenance problems, when we change a to-many-relationship into a to-one-relationship or vice-versa.

I would like to use the above annotations for "fields", "parameter methods" and "return parameters".

For example:

```
class MyClass {
   String @any name; // instead of using List<String>, i would like to use @any 

   public String setFullname(String @option name) { // @option is another multiplicity
       ...
   } 
}
```

To allow this definition, i have to change the JAVA-API and extends it with these two annotations, but I don't know how to do this.

Can you tell me how to change the API, and which steps I must follow to achieve my requirements?

---

Please look at [this paper](https://www.google.de/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=3&ved=0CEUQFjAC&url=http%3A%2F%2Fmultiplicities-for-csharp.googlecode.com%2Ffiles%2FECOOP2013-9.pdf&ei=OXidUo3cG8vbsgaHyICoCA&usg=AFQjCNFonk5CgOG-Bs5gFKBg9JyginNWFg&bvm=bv.57155469,d.Yms) to understand the issue.

As explained in that paper, using multiplicities for building to-many relationship causes number of problems:

1. "It makes maintenance tedious and error-prone."
   << If the maintenance of a program requires a change of a relationship from to-one to to-many (or vice versa), nearly every occurrence of the variable representing this relationship in the program needs to be touched. In a language with static type checking, these occurrences
   will be identified by the compiler (as type errors) after the declaration of the field has been changed so that at least, no use is forgotten; in a language without it, the change is extremely error-prone>>
2. "It changes conditions of subtyping"
   << If S is a subtype of T, an expression of type S can be assigned to a variable (representing a to-one relationship) of type T. When the relationship is upgraded to to-many and the types of the expression and variable are changed to Collection and Collection to reflect this, the assignment is no longer well-typed [18]. To fix this, the use of a (former to-one and now tomany) variable must be restricted to retrieving elements of its collection, which may require substantial further code changes. We consider this dependency of
   subtyping on multiplicity to be awkward.>>
3. "It changes call semantics"
   Yet another manifestation of the discontinuity is that when a variable holding a related object is used as an actual parameter of a method
   call with call-by-value semantics, the method cannot change the value of the variable (i.e., to which object the variable points), and thus cannot change which object
   the variable’s owner is related to. By contrast, when the variable holds a collection of related objects, passing this variable by-value to a method allows the
   method to add and remove from the collection, and thus to change which objects the variable’s owner is related to, effectively giving the call by-reference semantics.
   We consider this dependency of semantics on multiplicity to be awkward. Surely, there is an easy fix to all problems stemming from the noted discontinuity:
   implement to-one relationships using containers also. For instance, the Option class in Scala has two subclasses, Some and None, where Some wraps an object of type
   E with an object of type Option, which can be substituted by None, so that the object and no object have a uniform access protocol (namely that of Option). By making Option
   implement the protocol of Collection, the above noted discontinuity will mostly disappear. However, doing so generalizes the problems of collections that stem from
   putting the content over the container. Specifically:
4. "Related objects have to be unwrapped before they can be used". 
   Using containers for keeping related objects, the operations executable on a variable representing the relationship are the operations of the container and not of the related objects. For instance, if cookies have the operation beNibbled(), the same operation can
   typically not be expected from a collection of cookies (since Collection is a general
   purpose class).
5. "It subjects substitutability to the rules of subtyping of generics". While the difference in subtyping between to-one and to-many variables (item 2 above) has been
   removed, the wrong version has survived: now, a to-one relationship with target type T, implemented as a field having type Option, cannot relate to an object of T’s subtype S (using Option, unless restrictions regarding replacement of the object are accepted).
6. "It introduces an aliasing problem". 
   While aliasing is a general problem of objectoriented programming (see, e.g., [11, 19]), the use of container objects to implement relationships introduces the special problem of aliasing the container: when two objects share the same container, the relationship of one object cannot evolve differently from that of the other. This may however not model the domain correctly, and can lead to subtle programming errors.
7. "Expressive poverty". 
   More generally, given only collections it is not possible to
   express the difference between “object a has a collection, which contains objects b1 through bn” and “object a has objects b1 through bn”. While one might maintain that the former is merely the object-oriented way of representing the latter, and that the used collection is merely an implementation object, it could be the case that the collection is actually a domain object (as which it could even have aliases; cf. above). In object-oriented modelling, by contrast, collections serving as implementation classes are abstracted from by specifying multiplicities larger than 1 (possibly complemented by constraints on the type of the collection, i.e., whether it is ordered, has duplicates, etc.). A collection class in a domain model is therefore always a domain class.

The following figure highlights these problems using a sample program from the internet service provider domain.

http://infochrist.net/coumcoum/Multiplicities.png

Initially, a customer can have a single email account which, according to the price plan selected, is either a POP3 or an IMAP account. Accounts are created by a factory (static method Account.make, Figure 1 left, beginning in line 4) and, for reasons of symmetry, are also deleted by a static method (Account.delete; line 19); due to Java’s lack of support for calling by reference (or out parameters), however, delete does not work as expected. Therefore, resetting of the field account to null has been replicated in the method Customer.transferAccount (line 40). When the program is upgraded to support multiple accounts per customer, the first change is to alter the type of account to List (Figure 1 right, line 30). As suggested by above Problem 1, this entails a number of changes. In class Customer it requires the introduction of an iteration over all accounts (line 35), and the replacement of the receiver of the method set, account, with the iteration variable a (Problem 4). In class Account, make must be changed to return a list of accounts (line 4), and the construction of accounts (lines 7 and 12) must be replaced by the construction of lists that contain a single account of the appropriate type. Admittedly, making the Account factory return a list seems awkward; yet, as we will see, it only demonstrates Problem 7. Also, it brings about a change in the conditions of subtyping (Problem 2): for make to be well-typed (which it is not in Figure 1, right), its return type would either have to be changed to List (requiring a corresponding change of the type of Customer.account, thus limiting account’s use to read access; Problem 5), or the created lists would need to be changed to element type Account. The parameter type of Account.delete needs to be changed to List also; replacing the assignment
of null with clearing the list (line 20) to better reflect the absence of an account (cf. the above discussions on the different meanings of null) makes delete work as intended, which may however change the semantics of a program actually calling delete (Problem 3). An analogous change from assigning null to calling clear() in class Account, line 40, introduces a logical error, since the transferred account is accidentally cleared as well (Problem 6).

The solution is to use multiplicities, as followed (look at the comment below for the image):

The question is now, how can I implement multiplicities in Java?

Comment: Why do you think this belongs in the Java SDK?

Answer (score 3):

You are confused about what API means. To implement this idea, you would need to edit the source code of the Java compiler, and what you would end up with would no longer be Java, it would be a forked version of Java, which you would have to call something else.

I do not think this idea has much merit, to be honest.

Comment: You're write, i mean editing the source code of java to introduce multiplicities.

Answer (score 1):

It's unclear why you think this would solve your problem, and using a non-standard JDK will -- in fact -- give you an even greater maintenance burden. For example, when there are new versions of the JDK, you will need to apply your updates to the new version as well when you upgrade. Not to mention the fact that new employees you hire will not be familiar with your language that deviates from Java.

Java does allow one to define custom annotations:
http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/guide/language/annotations.html

... and one can use reflection or annotation processors to do cool things with them. **However**, annotations cannot be used to so drastically change the program semantics (like magically making a String mean a List of strings, instead) without forking your own version of the JDK, which is a bad idea.